# Как сделать FullScreen приложение?

Tags: android

Как сделать FullScreen приложение? В теме не получиться так как у меня тема своя. Но может можно добавить сюда?

```
<style name="txt_style" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
    <item name ="android:windowBackground">@drawable/wallpaper</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#2edb3f</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в свою основную тему приложения следующие атрибуты:

```
<item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```